# How Can I catch Bar Code Scan Value Without input Text focused on Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Please i try to integrate Barcode to my Application , but i want to catch scanned value without making focus text input ?
my Tried Code :

```
// on Form Key Press
TimeSpan elapsed = (DateTime.Now - _lastKeystroke);
    if (elapsed.TotalMilliseconds > 100)
        _barcode.Clear();
    // record keystroke & timestamp
    _barcode.Add(e.KeyChar);
    _lastKeystroke = DateTime.Now;
    // process barcode
    if (e.KeyChar == 13 && _barcode.Count > 0)
    { 
        string msg = new String(_barcode.ToArray());          
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As is now, your question is off-topic.

Comment: please add the code you have tried